# how to import a .csv file from MacBook to jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, macos

I am working with Jupyter and I want to import a .csv file from my MacBook but it can not find the file.
I use

```py
 pd.read_csv(⁩'/Users/sara/desktop/file_name.csv', encoding='ansi')
```

Comment: do you run jupyter on server ? then upload file on server first and then use path to this file on server.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have renamed your desktop folder, it should probably be `/Users/sara/Desktop/file_name.csv`.  Mac file paths are case-sensitive and the desktop folder is capitalized by default.